# WPF ScrollViewer changing TextBlock width

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, textblock

I have a simple dialog with a TextBlock that should resize with the window and show scrollbars when the content is wider than the TextBlock/Dialog. Without the ScrollViewer, it works fine - the TextBlock is as wide as the window. As soon as I add the ScrollViewer, the TextBlock gets much wider (it fits to the content width). Why is the ScrollViewer changing the TextBlock's behavior and how can I prevent this?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="A label"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Gray">
            <TextBlock MinHeight="200" MinWidth="600"
                       Text="Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... Some long text ... " />
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>        
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="80" Margin="0 10 15 15" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="OK"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why do you add a `ScrollViewer` in the first place if you don't want to be able to scroll the `TextBlock`? If you only want to be able to scroll vertically, you should set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Disabled`. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I do want to scroll the content, of course. But the ScrollViewer is making the TextBlock wider than the window which looks ugly. I want to scroll within the TextBlock which should be as wide as the window. The accepted solution did the trick, I still don't understand why. ;)

Comment: If if doesn't make the `TextBlock` wider, how is it supposed to scroll it...?

Comment: I don't want to scroll inside the window in order to get to the right border of the TextBlock. I want to scroll within the TextBlock. Maybe it makes the TextBlock wider internally, ok, but visually it should just keep it's width and not grow out of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ScrollViewer provides your controls as many space as they need and helps to scroll them. I think your problems is border, you just need to place ScrollViewer inside border, and everything will look good.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't quite get your question.
You want the TextBlock to resize with the window/dialog.
With or without the ScrollViewer, the TextBlock will resize accordingly with the window.
The ScrollViewer just let you scoll the content of an element, in this case TextBlock, when the content isn't fitting on the screen. There isn't any problem with your code, it's just the visual representation that's confusing you. :) Hope you get it.

Comment: No, the problem is that the ScrollViewer made the TextBlock fit it's content, so it got wider than the window. The accepted answer solved it. Thank you!